# I cannot solve this equatition, using ode45 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode45

dθ/dτ=-θ-b*θ^4

I need to solve this equation by ode45
 I tried the following way but I dont sure if it is true

```
[t,a]=ode45('fonks', [0 120], 1)
```

plot (t,a)

---

```
function x=fonks(t,a)
b=0.5;
x=-t+b*t^4;
```

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: instead of 'fonks' try @fonks as argument to the ode45 function

Comment: Also, it looks like you are adding b^4 instead of subtracting it in your function `fonks`

Comment: I just realized I had mistyped it... thanks for helps

Comment: Voting to close due to simple typo.